# how to pickup a random item from a Map Ecma6 object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
map = new Map([
    [ 1, 'one' ],
    [ 2, 'two' ],
    [ 3, 'three' ], 
]);
```

How can I retrieve a random item from map ?

Comment: Generate a random number between 1 and 3 then get this number

Comment: maybe [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is not the right data structure for random elements.

Comment: Do you know how to use `Math.random`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function nth(x, iterable) {
    for (const el of iterable)
        if (x-- == 0)
            return el;
    throw new Error("not found");
}

console.log(nth(Math.floor(Math.random() * map.size), map.values())) // or keys or entries
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get first the values of the map in an array and then take the length of the array as random factor and take the value at the random index.

```js
var map = new Map([[1, 'one'], [2, 'two'], [3, 'three']]),
    values = [...map.values()],
    random = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];

console.log(random);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys in the Map were sequential, you would get a random number between `1` and `Map.length`, then retrieve the value from the Map corresponding to that random number.

```js
map = new Map([
    [ 1, 'one' ],
    [ 2, 'two' ],
    [ 3, 'three' ], 
]);

const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * map.size) + 1;
const randomFromMap = map.get(rand);
console.log(randomFromMap);
```

If the keys were not sequential, or not integers, you would need to use `Map.prototype.keys()` to return the keys as an array and then retrieve the random element using a random element from the keys array. Something like:

```js
const map = new Map([
    [ 1, 'one' ],
    [ 2, 'two' ],
    [ 3, 'three' ], 
]);

const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * map.size);
const mapKeys = Array.from(map.keys());
console.log(map.get(mapKeys[rand]))
```

Comment: `Math.floor(x)+1` is not the same as `Math.ceil(x)`. Your code has (small but existing) chance to fail

Comment: `entries()` doesn't return an array, you need `Array.from(…)` to convert the iterator

Answer (score -1):

Create an array from the map and pick a random key. You can use `Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))` to create a "dice" value for your array.

```js
map = new Map([
    [ 1, 'one' ],
    [ 2, 'two' ],
    [ 3, 'three' ], 
]);

let array = Array.from(map);
let dice = Math.round(Math.random() * (array.length - 1))
let value = array[dice];

// value contains an array with key/value pair.
console.log(value);
```

Comment: I suppose by "random" the OP meant to imply "with equal probability".